# webpack-dev-server version 4 causing app to infinite refresh

Tags: webpack-dev-server

I have recently upgraded my React application to use `webpack-dev-server: 4.8.1` however now my application is stuck in an infinite refresh loop when trying to start it in a browser.

The error in my browser console that I can see is around [authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMZ2Q.png). The authentication error occurs in the point in time when my application doing a redirect to sign in and this is when the infinite refresh starts to happen.

The webpack logs when the refresh occurs shows that there is an invalid request.

```
webpack 5.72.0 compiled successfully in 1072 ms
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /?error_description=invalid_scope&state=RthU8qbnTzthhO7OGWIKMizM9lcuxxwx&error=invalid_request
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /?error_description=invalid_scope&state=TnqdsuTRrf0vgy4Q5KanPdrjQxIE0v24&error=invalid_request
```

**My `webpack-dev.js` file** (what's in `webpack.common` is a bunch of rules and plugins which I have ommitted since I don't believe it is causing the issue):

```
import path from 'path';
import merge from 'webpack-merge';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import common from './webpack.common';

export default merge(common, {
mode: 'development',
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        importLoaders: 1,
                        modules: {
                            localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:3]',
                        },
                    }
                },
                'postcss-loader'
            ]
        }
    ],
},

output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../dist/localdev'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'app/[name].js',
},
devServer: {
    hot: "only",
    open: false,
    static : {
        directory : path.join(__dirname, "./dist/localdev")
      },
    devMiddleware: {
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
},
});
```

Not sure if related but when I had to remove `inline: true` from the devServer config since it was removed with no replacement in v4 this seems to have started to happen.